# What is the best way to make a LINQ-to-XML statement dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm loading XML data into an object with this LINQ statement:

```
var smartFormFields = from smartFormField in xmlDoc.Descendants("smartFormField")
                      select new Models.SmartFormField
                      {
                          IdCode = smartFormField.Element("idCode").Value,
                          Label = smartFormField.Element("label").Value,
                          FieldType = smartFormField.Element("fieldType").Value,
                          DisplayStatus = smartFormField.Element("displayStatus").Value,
                          RequiredStatus = smartFormField.Element("requiredStatus").Value,
                          DisplayColumn = (int)smartFormField.Element("displayColumn"),
                          DisplayOrder = (int)smartFormField.Element("displayOrder"),
                          Description = smartFormField.Element("description").Value,
                          Example = smartFormField.Element("example").Value,
                          ControlType = smartFormField.Element("controlType").Value,
                          AutoSuggestDataSource = smartFormField.Element("autoSuggestDataSource").Value
                      };
```

**However, my WHERE (and ORDERBY) statement will change each time, e.g.**

it may be this:

```
var smartFormFields = from smartFormField in xmlDoc.Descendants("field")
                      where smartFormField.Element("IdCode").Value == "lastName"
                      select new Models.SmartFormField
                      {...
```

it may be this:

```
var smartFormFields = from smartFormField in xmlDoc.Descendants("field")
                      where (int)smartFormField.Element("DisplayOrder").Value > 50
                      select new Models.SmartFormField
                      {...
```

etc.

**How can I put the Where statement into a variable, something like this:**

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
string whereStatement = "where (int)smartFormField.Element(\"DisplayOrder\").Value > 50";

var smartFormFields = from smartFormField in xmlDoc.Descendants("field")
                      &&whereStatement
                      select new Models.SmartFormField
                      {...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to express it as a string? If you're happy to supply it as a delegate, you can use:

```
// Just as one example of a where clause
Func<XElement, bool> whereClause = sff => (int) sff.Element("DisplayOrder").Value > 50;

var smartFormFields = xmlDoc.Descendants("field")
                            .Where(whereClause)
                            .Select(sff => 
                                new Models.SmartFormField
                                {
                                    IdCode = sff.Element("idCode").Value,
                                    ...
                                });
```

If you put this into a method, then you just need to use a lambda expression:

```
var fields = GetFormFields(sff => (int) sff.Element("DisplayOrder").Value > 50);
```

etc

That will let you easily supply different values for different calls, but you won't be able to just put the expressions into a text file without a bit more work. What are your real requirements here? Could you have a map of "filter name" to `Func<XElement, bool>`, and then read the filter names at execution time? Or do you really need it to be *fully* controlled at execution time, in an arbitrary way?

(Note that ordering is similar but probably slightly trickier... let's get the filtering sorted first.)

Comment: very interesting, requirements are: be able to parse various "load codes" from the constructor to load various groups from the XML file, so I will just have a switch statement that converts text into delegates, let build try to build this in...

Comment: I'd just have a Dictionary<string, Func<XElement, bool>> and use that rather than a switch statement.

Comment: though it is not my post but still i like to request u to post a full small working sample of using string in LINQ like `xmlDoc.Descendants("field")
.Where(whereClause)`

Comment: @Thomas: Well what more do you need than is in there? The `...` would just be a lambda expression.

Comment: the `where delegate function code` is not completed. i need to see how where delegate code would look like..because i am not familiar with that kind of where clause. thanks

Comment: @Thomas: Well the final part showed an example... but I've changed the `...` to an example lambda expression...

Comment: thanks, we could write this way whole thing....then why u use delegate function as separate one...any special reason was there ? `var smartFormFields = xmlDoc.Descendants("field")
.Where(e=> e.Element("DisplayOrder").Value > 50)
.Select(sff => 
new Models.SmartFormField
{
    IdCode = sff.Element("idCode").Value,
    ...
});`

Comment: @Thomas: The point is that the OP wants to pass the delegate into the method, or perhaps choose between multiple different options within the same method.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your reply :)