# How can I get this dynamic WHERE statement in my LINQ-to-XML to work?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, linq-to-xml

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969661/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-linq-to-xml-statement-dynamic/969692#969692) Jon Skeet offered a **very interesting solution** to making a LINQ-to-XML statement dynamic, but my knowledge of lambdas and delegates is not yet advanced enough to implement it:

I've got it **this far**, but of course I get the error "smartForm does not exist in the current context":

```
private void LoadWithId(int id)
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = null;
    try
    {
        xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(FullXmlDataStorePathAndFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Cannot load XML file: {0}", ex.Message));
    }

    Func<XElement, bool> whereClause = (int)smartForm.Element("id") == id";

    var smartForms = xmlDoc.Descendants("smartForm")
        .Where(whereClause)
        .Select(smartForm => new SmartForm
                     {
                         Id = (int)smartForm.Element("id"),
                         WhenCreated = (DateTime)smartForm.Element("whenCreated"),
                         ItemOwner = smartForm.Element("itemOwner").Value,
                         PublishStatus = smartForm.Element("publishStatus").Value,
                         CorrectionOfId = (int)smartForm.Element("correctionOfId"),
                         IdCode = smartForm.Element("idCode").Value,
                         Title = smartForm.Element("title").Value,
                         Description = smartForm.Element("description").Value,
                         LabelWidth = (int)smartForm.Element("labelWidth")
                     });

    foreach (SmartForm smartForm in smartForms)
    {
        _collection.Add(smartForm);
    }
}
```

**Ideally** I want to be able to just say:

```
var smartForms = GetSmartForms(smartForm=> (int) smartForm.Element("DisplayOrder").Value > 50);
```

I've got it this far, but **I'm just not grokking the lambda magic**, how do I do this?

```
public List<SmartForm> GetSmartForms(XDocument xmlDoc, XElement whereClause)
{
    var smartForms = xmlDoc.Descendants("smartForm")
        .Where(whereClause)
        .Select(smartForm => new SmartForm
                     {
                         Id = (int)smartForm.Element("id"),
                         WhenCreated = (DateTime)smartForm.Element("whenCreated"),
                         ItemOwner = smartForm.Element("itemOwner").Value,
                         PublishStatus = smartForm.Element("publishStatus").Value,
                         CorrectionOfId = (int)smartForm.Element("correctionOfId"),
                         IdCode = smartForm.Element("idCode").Value,
                         Title = smartForm.Element("title").Value,
                         Description = smartForm.Element("description").Value,
                         LabelWidth = (int)smartForm.Element("labelWidth")
                     });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you mean:

```
public List<SmartForm> GetSmartForms(
       XDocument xmlDoc, Func<XElement,bool> whereClause)
```

and:

```
Func<XElement, bool> whereClause = smartForm => (int)smartForm.Element("id") == id;
```

To use as a method, I would make it `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<SmartForm> GetSmartForms(
       XDocument xmlDoc, Func<XElement,bool> predicate)
    {
        return xmlDoc.Descendants("smartForm")
            .Where(predicate)
            .Select(smartForm => new SmartForm
            {
                ... snip
            });
    }
```

and call as:

```
            foreach (SmartForm smartForm in GetSmartForms(xmlDoc,
                sf => (int)sf.Element("id") == id))
            {
                _collection.Add(smartForm);
            }
```

Comment: brilliant, this (1) worked, (2) was exactly what I needed, (3) taught me something about lambdas seeing them solve my own issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just not grokking the lambda magic,

Marc's answer addresses the scenario you have.  My answer will attempt to address the lambda magic you are missing.

lambda expressions have three parts: parameters arrow methodbody

```
Func<int, int, int> myFunc =  (x, i) => x * i ;
```

For **parameters**, these must be enclosed in parens except in the case of a single parameter.  This section introduces variable names into the scope.  Since you didn't supply parameters in your lambda, you didn't have any variable names.

**arrow** is required, since you didn't have an arrow, the compiler didn't know you were making a lambda.

For **methodbody**, if it's a one-liner, return is implied.  Otherwise, open a curly brace and make a method body like you normally would.