# Dynamic Linq to Xml example

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, dynamic-linq

I need a basic example on how to use System.Linq.Dynamic with Xml. Here’s a functioning statement I want to convert to dynamic Linq:

```
XElement e = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(XmlDoc));
var results =
    from r in e.Elements("TABLES").Descendants("AGREEMENT")
    where (string)r.Element("AGRMNT_TYPE_CODE") == "ISDA"
    select r.Element("DATE_SIGNED");

foreach (var x in results)
{
    result = x.Value;
    break;
}
```

Here’s the approach I am using:

```
string whereClause = "(\"AGRMNT_TYPE_CODE\") == \"ISDA\"";
string selectClause = "(\"DATE_SIGNED\")";
var results = e.Elements("TABLES").Descendants<XElement>("AGREEMENT").
                AsQueryable<XElement>().
                Where<XElement>(whereClause).
                Select(selectClause); 

foreach (var x in results)
{
    result = (string)x;
    break;
}
```

It executes without error but produces no results.

I am trying to code this similar to the canonical example found at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx where a constructed string is applied against a database:

```
Dim Northwind as New NorthwindDataContext
Dim query = Northwind.Products _
                     .Where("CategoryID=2 and UnitPrice>3") _
                     .OrderBy("SupplierId")
GridView1.Datasource = query
GridView1.Databind()
```

What am I missing?

---

I finally got it working. I abandoned my original approach because as of now I'm not convinced it was even intended for use with Xml. I've seen little posted anywhere to argue against that statement. Instead, I used Jon Skeet's response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969661/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-linq-to-xml-statement-dynamic/969692#969692) as the basis for my answer:

```
XElement e = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(XmlDoc));

List<Func<XElement, bool>> exps = new List<Func<XElement, bool>> { };
exps.Add(GetXmlQueryExprEqual("AGRMNT_TYPE_CODE", "ISDA"));
exps.Add(GetXmlQueryExprNotEqual("WHO_SENDS_CONTRACT_IND", "X"));

List<ConditionalOperatorType> condOps = new List<ConditionalOperatorType> { };
condOps.Add(ConditionalOperatorType.And);
condOps.Add(ConditionalOperatorType.And);

//Hard-coded test value of the select field Id will be resolved programatically in the
//final version, as will the preceding literal constants.
var results = GetValueFromXml(171, e, exps, condOps);

foreach (var x in results)
{
    result = x.Value;
break;
}

return result;
...
public static Func<XElement, bool> GetXmlQueryExprEqual(string element, string compare)
{
    try
    {
        Expression<Func<XElement, bool>> expressExp = a => (string)a.Element(element) == compare;
        Func<XElement, bool> express = expressExp.Compile();
        return express;
    }   
    catch (Exception e)     
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static Func<XElement, bool> GetXmlQueryExprNotEqual(string element, string compare)
{
    try
    {
        Expression<Func<XElement, bool>> expressExp = a => (string)a.Element(element) != compare;
        Func<XElement, bool> express = expressExp.Compile();
        return express;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<XElement> GetValueFromXml(int selectFieldId, XElement elem, 
    List<Func<XElement, bool>> predList, List<ConditionalOperatorType> condOpsList)
{
    try
    {
        string fieldName = DocMast.GetFieldName(selectFieldId);
        string xmlPathRoot = DocMast.Fields[true, selectFieldId].XmlPathRoot;
        string xmlPathParent = DocMast.Fields[true, selectFieldId].XmlPathParent;
        IEnumerable<XElement> results = null;
        ConditionalOperatorType condOp = ConditionalOperatorType.None; 

    switch (predList.Count)
    {
        case (1):
          results =
            from r in elem.Elements(xmlPathRoot).Descendants(xmlPathParent)
            where (predList[0](r))
            select r.Element(fieldName);
          break;
        case (2):
            CondOp = (ConditionalOperatorType)condOpsList[0];
            switch (condOp)
            {  
                case (ConditionalOperatorType.And):
                    results =
                    from r in elem.Elements(xmlPathRoot).Descendants(xmlPathParent)
                    where (predList[0](r) && predList[1](r))
                    select r.Element(fieldName);
                    break;
                case (ConditionalOperatorType.Or):
                    results =
                    from r in elem.Elements(xmlPathRoot).Descendants(xmlPathParent)
                    where (predList[0](r) || predList[1](r))
                    select r.Element(fieldName);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return results;
}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This approach, however, is obviously far from perfect.

1. I have separate functions for resolving and compiling the expressions-- just to incorporate different conditional operators. What's worse, I will be adding more to support additional logical operators and numeric values;
2. The GetValueFromXml routine is clunky and will have to grow additional cases as I add more parameters.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here really, your where clause:

```
("AGMNT_TYPE_CODE") == "ISDA"
```

... will of course evaluate to `false`, because they are both strings.

The second issue is that the `ExpressionParser` is limited in scope, it can only do comparisons on a set of predefined types. You need to recompile the Dynamic library and either allow some additional types (you can do this by modifying the `predefinedTypes` static field of the `ExpressionParser` type) or, remove the check for predefined types (which is what I have done previously):

```
Expression ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression instance)
{
  // ...
        switch (FindMethod(type, id, instance == null, args, out mb))
        {
            case 0:
                throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.NoApplicableMethod,
                    id, GetTypeName(type));
            case 1:
                MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo)mb;
                //if (!IsPredefinedType(method.DeclaringType)) // Comment out this line, and the next.
                    //throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.MethodsAreInaccessible, GetTypeName(method.DeclaringType));
                if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
                    throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.MethodIsVoid,
                        id, GetTypeName(method.DeclaringType));
                return Expression.Call(instance, (MethodInfo)method, args);
            default:
                throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.AmbiguousMethodInvocation,
                    id, GetTypeName(type));
        }
  // ...
}
```

Those lines I have commented out are where the check for predefined types are done.

Once you have made that change, you need to update your query (remember, `ExpressionParser` builds expressions that are compiled, so simply using `"(\"AGRMNT_TYPE_CODE\") == \"ISDA\""` wont work.  You would need something like:

```
string where = "Element(\"AGMNT_TYPE_CODE\").Value == \"ISDA\"";
```

Comment: I have previously tried: 
string where = "Element(\"AGMNT_TYPE_CODE\").Value == \"ISDA\""; and it produces a System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 
"No applicable method 'Element' exists in type 'XElement'". It seems like this general approach should work. (see my addition to the original post above) I'm sure it's just a matter of the correct syntax. I have been unsuccessfully doing trial and error repeatedly before making this posting.

Answer (score 0):

Following this form of a template may assist you:

```
Nodes = (from N in xDoc.Elements(NodeName)
where (string)N.Element("AGMNT_TYPE_CODE") == "ISDA"
select N);
```