# No property or field 'OrderID' exists in type 'XElement' (at index 0)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, dynamic-linq

i am reading a xml file and querying by LINQ this below way

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
var query = document.Descendants("orders").Select(c => c);
query = query.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + OrderDirection);

query = query.Skip(lowerPageBoundary - 1 * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);

DataTable table = query.ToList().ConvertToDataTable();
table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
//adapter.Fill(table);
return table;
```

but getting error **No property or field 'OrderID' exists in type 'XElement' (at index 0)**

this is my sample xml which i am querying by LINQ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
    <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
    <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>
    <RequiredDate>1996-08-01T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
    <ShippedDate>1996-07-16T00:00:00</ShippedDate>
    <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
    <Freight>32.3800</Freight>
    <ShipName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</ShipName>
    <ShipAddress>59 rue de l'Abbaye</ShipAddress>
    <ShipCity>Reims</ShipCity>
    <ShipPostalCode>51100</ShipPostalCode>
    <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
  </Orders>
</Root>
```

in debug mode i expand the result view and found order id exist. here is screen shot.
[image]

so tell me where i made the mistake in code. please guide. thanks

Comment: Why do you have `.Select(c => c)`? That doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 1):

What are `sortColumn` and `OrderDirection`? By the usage it looks like they are strings, but `OrderBy` doesn't take a string unless you're using Dynamic LINQ.

LINQ to XML doesn't give you properties for Elements. If you have an `XElement e`, you wouldn't be able to call `e.OrderID`. You must use the `Element` method like this `e.Element("OrderID").Value`. To plug that into the `OrderBy` method, you could do this:

```
query = query.OrderBy(e => e.Element("OrderID").Value);
```

As the comment points out, adding `.Select(c => c)` doesn't do anything. Also, you could chain the remaining methods like this:

```
var query = document.Descendants("orders")
                    .OrderBy(e => e.Element("OrderID").Value)
                    .Skip(lowerPageBoundary - 1 * rowsPerPage)
                    .Take(rowsPerPage);
```

With Dynamic LINQ, you'll still need to use the Element method. [Dynamic Linq to Xml example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586084/dynamic-linq-to-xml-example) suggests that it should be something like this, but I haven't tested it:

```
var query = document.Descendants("orders")
                    .OrderBy(String.Format("Element(\"{0}\").Value {1}", sortColumn, OrderDirection))
                    .Skip(lowerPageBoundary - 1 * rowsPerPage)
                    .Take(rowsPerPage);
```

It should be possible without using Dynamic LINQ since you have to use the `Element` method and pass in the name of the column you're sorting by anyway. You'd just need to branch and use `OrderByDescending` when `OrderDirection` is "descending."

Comment: Dynamic LINQ. was used to sort and order data from xml. so i used the below code

sort column name and sort order passed as argument to function.

query = query.OrderBy("OrderID"+ " " + "DESC");

so give your code which will work for Dynamic LINQ.

my situation is like that sort column and order can be anything and that is why i used Dynamic LINQ to handle the situation because only with the help of Dynamic LINQ we can write text in OrderByFunction.

Comment: i am using Dynamic LINQ. so like to know your above code will work for  Dynamic LINQ. in ur above code can i pass sort column name and sort order. let me know. thanks

Comment: thanks for answer. u said `It should be possible without using Dynamic LINQ` would you mind to show how to handle this situation without Dynamic LINQ. thanks

Comment: When i run your last code where Dynamic linq is used then i got a error "No applicable method 'Element' exists in type 'XElement'  " can u help me to fix it.

Comment: `XElement` does have the `Element` method, so maybe that's a bug in Dynamic LINQ or it just doesn't support doing it like that. My first 2 examples are how to use the standard `OrderBy` without using the Dynamic LINQ version.